# Infinite loop in my overloaded >> operator when checking for errors

Tags: c++, error-handling, operator-overloading, infinite-loop, cin

```
std::istream & operator >>(std::istream & ins, Rational & target)
{
    int num, den;
    char symb;          
    std::cout << "Please enter a rational number: ";
    ins >> num >> symb >> den;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if(validateInput(num, symb, den)){
        target = Rational(num, den);            
        return ins;
    }
    else{
        std::cin >> target;
    }
}

bool validateInput(int num, char symb, int den)
{
    if(symb != '/'){
        std::cout << "Error: Illegal format. Please use '2/4'." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    if((static_cast<int>(num) != num) && (static_cast<int>(den) != den)){
        std::cout << "Error: Not a valid rational number." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    if(den == 0){
        std::cout << "Error: Cannot divide by 0." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

It's taking in a rational number in the format 'x/y', so 2/4 for instance. 
It works fine if I type it right. If I type in 2p4, it will give the correct error (that I'm missing a '/') and then ask for a new number. If 0 is in the denominator, it will also report the error and ask for a new number.

But checking to see if it's a valid number doesn't seem to work. If I type in 'a/4', it will just loop infinitely until it crashes. I can't figure out why. Checking the debugger, it goes back to the ins >> statement, but doesn't ask for anything from the user.

I'm assuming my logic is wrong somewhere. Note, I'm fairly new to C++, still learning. I was trying exception handling earlier, still haven't learned it properly, so I settled back on something I'm more familiar with.

Thanks!

Comment: This code appears to go against good practise for operator overloading and could be improved. First, do not prompt the user for values via cout since the console may not be available, such as if the application is running in the background. Second, your static_cast statements in `validateinput()` will always work because the input has already been parsed into these types in the line `ins >> num >> symb >> den;`. Third, the validation should be performed in the Rational constructor. It should throw an exception if the values are invalid but I accept that you are working toward that.

Comment: I probably should have been more specific in my post. It's a console app, it's a project I was assigned for class. I would like the Rational constructor to validate, but the thing is, the project specifically asks for the program to ask the user to enter a rational number in this format: '2/4'. So when it asks me for the first number, I have to type in 2/4. The rational constructor wouldn't be able to check if the / was typed in, so that's why I validate in the >> function. I could be very wrong on this, as I'm pretty new, so please correct if I am! Thanks

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, first, I would not be prompting the user in the operator overload. I would move it to a different function for reasons given above. Second, using `ins >> num >> symb >> den;` to pull in the data allows whitespace between each of the elements. I do not know what the specification is but that may not be allowed. You may want to `ins >> num;` then use ins.peek() to see what the next character is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic gist of the issue is that C++ streams formatted extraction operators stop working if the state of the stream goes bad, and you have to reset the state for them to work again.

You have other issues, as well.

First of all, your validation function reveals your lack of experience: `static_cast<int>(intval) == intval` will always be true and confirms nothing. Secondly, you fail to verify that you have indeed succeeded in extracting values from the stream (this is the cause for your infinite loop: all you do is fail the verification over and over again.)

So, when you extract values, you should verify that all went alright, like this:

```
int num, den;
char symb;
// Remember to flush unfinished lines
std::cout << "Please enter a rational number: " << std::flush; 
if (std::cin >> num >> symb >> den)
    // you extracted an integer, a character and an integer succesfully
    // perhaps check that the character is '/' and denominator is non-zero
else
    // there was an error: what should we do?
```

The "what should we do" part is far from obvious: you *could* just reset the stream and remove the first offending byte from it and try again, if you think that's reasonable (and intuitive). However, the extraction may have also failed due to too large numbers, in which case this may lead odd behaviour: consider the following input (on an implementation with common `long` size):

```
3111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111/3
```

If you haven't got any actual specifications, a thing to consider would be line-orientated input: first read a line and try to parse it; if it doesn't look OK, ignore it and try the next one.

Answer (score 0):

One of the important concepts for input streams is that they are not tied to any particular device; that is, `str >> rational` should work when `str` is the console, when it's a file, when it's a string, whatever. So an extractor should extract. It shouldn't prompt, and it shouldn't explain what it didn't like. All those things should be done in the code that calls the extractor.

Validation in an extractor is fine, but when an error is detected, the usual way of reporting it is to throw an exception. You can make your exceptions do whatever you like, holding an error code or a text string, or having different exceptions for different errors. It's the responsibility of the code that calls the extractor to catch exceptions and decide what the appropriate response is.

```
static_cast<int>(num) != num
```

Since `num` is an int, the `static_cast` doesn't do anything. This test will never fail.

int main() {
    try {
        std::cout << "Please enter a rational number: ";
        Rational r;
        std::cin >> r;
    }
    catch(...) {
        std::cout << "Something went wrong\n";
    }
}

For testing purposes, I'd rewrite this version of `main()` to use a stringstream as the input source, and initialize it with `"2/4"` or `"2^4"` or whatever I wanted to test with; that would save having to type the input each time.